# SQL Join - Query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

So I would like to display the most experience player, at first I was going to display all players and experiencepoints then try and only display the max. so heres the code for both tables and the query itself

```
CREATE TABLE Player    
(    
  Player_ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_player PRIMARY KEY,    
  Pname VARCHAR(60),  
  DOB    VARCHAR(10),    
  Heightcm NUMBER(10),    
  Weightkg NUMBER(10),    
  Position VARCHAR(20),    
  Team_ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT fk_player REFERENCES Team(Team_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE PlayerCareer_Performance   
(    
  Player_Performance_ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_PP PRIMARY KEY,    
  Player_ID INTEGER,    
  total_points NUMBER(10),    
  total_fouls NUMBER(10),    
  ExperiencePoints NUMBER(10),    
  CONSTRAINT fk_Pp FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Player(Player_ID)
)
```

Thats the table code, below is the query:

```
SELECT PLAYER.PLAYER_ID,PLAYER.PNAME,PLAYERCAREER_PERFORMANCE.EXPERIENCEPOINTS    
FROM PLAYER    
JOIN PLAYERCAREER_PERFOMANCE    
ON PLAYERPERFROMANCE.PLAYER_ID = PLAYER.PLAYER_ID;
```

Player is underlined on yellow and it says "Is disconnected from the rest of join graph"

Any ideas, anyone? I cant see a fix for it :(

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, you are joining the table `PLAYERCAREER_PERFORMANCE` but joining on a field of table called `PLAYERPERFROMANCE` *(sic)*. Is that a typo?

This:

```
SELECT Player.Player_ID, Player.Pname, PlayerCareer_Performance.ExperiencePoints
FROM Player
JOIN PlayerCareer_Performance 
ON PlayerCareer_Performance.Player_ID = Player.Player_ID
```

Seems to work fine (just corrected the typo): [check it at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/196e15/10).

As a general suggestion, keep your code consistent... you are using different column formats (e.g.: `ExperiencePoints` vs `total_points`), and are putting all SQL query code in caps, which just makes it difficult to read and find typos

Comment: +10 Personally, I find the SQL easier to decipher when short table aliases are assigned to the table references (e.g. "p"  for player, and "c" for playercareer_performance, and then qualify *all* column references with the aliases. I also prefer to use all lowercase for identifiers. (That's  just my personal preference. None of that is actually *required*, other patterns are used successfully.)

Comment: I use the short aliases aswell, just didn't want to modify the OPs answer too much... just provided some "decent" formatting and wanted to point out the typo, since the query doesn't look wrong without it :-) Also formatted the question, if you check the edit history you'll see his "formatting" before I fixed it :-)

Comment: YOU GOD! thank you and it was the typo :( i really need to stop doing that, yes making it shorter would be a good idea, going to try and display only the player with the most Experincepoints now, if i struggle ill post again tomorrow, thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join (updated to reflect popular demand):

```
select p.player_id, p.pname, pcp.experiencepoiuts
from Player p
inner join PlayerCareer_Performance pcp on pcp.player_id = p.player_id
```

Comment: You write `use an inner join` but your query doesn't have an `inner join`, you should make up your mind :-)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed sufficient understanding of SQL's default behavior (most engines) to use inner join.

Comment: Yes, it'll more likely do an inner join, just was wondering about the answer redaction (not that it is wrong :-) )

Comment: The comma is old-school syntax for a join operation. This statement does indeed perform an "inner join" operation. While that old-school comma syntax is supported (which is good in terms of supporting legacy SQL), newly authored SQL should make use of the newer JOIN keyword, and join predicates can be moved to an appropriate ON clause.  (The JOIN keyword has been around for so long, we can't really justify calling it "newer"... except in comparison with the much older comma syntax.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I agree (it does an inner join), but I'm not sure we even called them "joins" when using that format... it's been a long time, but I recall just calling that: "select from two tables"... the fact that the engine would make an inner join was an implementation detail :-D Then again, I'm just being picky with the redaction: the answer is not *wrong*, but also not saying what was wrong with the OPs question :-)

Comment: @Jcl: this answer makes it seem like OP query was *not* an inner join, which seems really odd. This answer corrects the problem with OP query, not by "using an inner join", but by correcting an invalidly qualified column reference. I'm not downvoting this answer, but I'm also not upvoting it, because it really isn't a good answer.)  I avoid using the AS keyword for assigning table aliases. Some databases allow it optionally, and other databases don't and throw a syntax error. I do always use the AS keyword for assigning column aliases, because I think it makes the statement easier to decipher.

Comment: @spencer7593 I definitely don't use it for table aliases, but do for aggregate or calculated column names (I guess that's just how I learned SQL and sticked to it)... not sure what is right or not, but that's my preference and has worked on every engine I've used :-)

Comment: Arent  INNER JOIN and JOIN THE SAME, also can I do it with one of them rather than the example you gave above??

Comment: Also it wont accept that statment (as p) the p is underlined red